# flutter SfCalendar(syncfusion calendar) error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

when i run my project android studio show me this error !

import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 7 Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_calendar-20.4.54/lib/src/calendar/sfcalendar.dart:10776:71: Error: A value of type 'RenderAbstractViewport?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'RenderAbstractViewport' because 'RenderAbstractViewport?' is nullable and 'RenderAbstractViewport' isn't.
 - 'RenderAbstractViewport' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart' ('/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart').
  RenderAbstractViewport get _stackViewPort => RenderAbstractViewport.of(this);
                                                                      ^
/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:7596:37: Error: The argument type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't.
 - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
        scrollableState: Scrollable.of(context),
                                    ^
/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:7611:40: Error: A value of type 'ScrollableState?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ScrollableState' because 'ScrollableState?' is nullable and 'ScrollableState' isn't.
 - 'ScrollableState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart' ('/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart').
        ..scrollableState = Scrollable.of(context)
                                       ^
/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-20.4.54/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:7665:71: Error: A value of type 'RenderAbstractViewport?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'RenderAbstractViewport' because 'RenderAbstractViewport?' is nullable and 'RenderAbstractViewport' isn't.
 - 'RenderAbstractViewport' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart' ('/C:/flutter_windows_3.0.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/viewport.dart').
  RenderAbstractViewport get _stackViewPort => RenderAbstractViewport.of(this);
                                                                      ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

i want't to show an event calendar in my flutter application

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.
i was using latest version(21.1.39)
now i'm using version :- 19.4.50
thank you!